# Memoria asignada al copiar y pegar código en NetBeans no funciona

Tags: java, netbeans, apache, javafx, apache-netbeans

ya en el anterior versión de NetBeans 19 y 20 al copiar o pegar de los apuntes código o controles de formulario bien jTextField, jTable, Jbutton,...no permite pegarlo directamente sin previamente pasar por un bloc de notas en el caso de código o con la opción de cortar los controles,...

He reiniciado el IDE, la máquina y actualizado, pero me ocurre igual en otros equipos de los que disponemos y la queja es general. Al inicio funciona bien, pero al cabo de unos copy/paste vuelve el error, enseñando o mostrando código enseñando estos es un horror,...

¿Sabéis si hay alguna solución?

Comment: El bug de copy paste a/desde netbeans lleva años en el IDE, hay algunos workarounds de esto pero hasta ahora no hay solución definitiva. https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/3962

Comment: Este es un problema relacionado con tu memoria RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las causas principales es la memoria asignada para tu IDE. Busca y edita tu archivo `netbeans.conf` y dentro de este archivo en `netbeans_default_options` y aumenta los valores de `Xmx` (heap size inicial) y -Xms (Máximo heap size asignado), por ejemplo:

```
-Xmx1g -Xms2g
```

para asignar 1 GB de memoria inicial y 2 GB de memoria máxima mientras uses Netbeans, al realizar estos cambios en tu archivo `netbeans.conf` reinicia tu IDE.